# WiX:Burn No Progress being posted back through CacheAcquireProgress

Tags: wix, burn

I'm modifying the sample installer provided by the BURN source code. 
I have been successful in creating a custom UI and some menu's, but, I have failed at attaching the progress bar to the status.

I have noticed that CacheAcquireBegin, CacheAcquireProgress, CacheAcquireComplete do not fire therefore my local progress variable does not change from 0 to anything.

In ProgressViewModel, I do see:

```
WiXBA.Model.Bootstrapper.CacheAcquireProgress += this.CacheAcquireProgress;
WiXBA.Model.Bootstrapper.CacheComplete += this.CacheComplete;
```

Which to me, would indicate that there are handlers attached to the functions that would generally post status messages. Everything else seems to work, i.e. the installation, the dialogs, etc. I just can't seem to post any progress.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880779/3820) answer `CacheAcquireProgress` is used to track the progress of downloading/copying of each package into the package cache. Your installer may not need to cache the packages, which is why this step is not firing.

The `Progress` event gives you overall installation progress.

The `ExecuteProgress` event gives you progress for an individual package during the install.